# Как добраться до Overlay в LoadingObjectManager?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

В документации к LoadingObjectManager (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/LoadingObjectManager-docpage/) есть событие 'overlaychange'. Когда оно вызывается? Пробовал пойти подругому использовал getOverlay у того же LOM, он ответил `ObjectManager doesn't have an overlay.
    at new BaseObjectManager.NoOverlayError`. Правильно ли я понимаю, что overlay - это объекты в области видимости, если да то ЧЯДНТ? Цель - поймать событие, когда меняются объекты в области видимости.

Comment: Вам нужно узнать когда добавляются новые объекты? Тогда подойдёт событие add https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.ObjectCollection-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-add

Comment: Add будет вызываться на каждый объект или на когда все вставятся? Кажется вы не поняли вопрос, или я неправильно объяснил. Объекты добавляются в LoadingObjectManager при загрузке так? А мне нужно посчитать кол-во меток на карте В МОМЕНТ когда эта область видимости меняется. Boundschange на карте работает, но при зуме не успевают загрузится объекты с сервера и число меток получается неправильное.

Comment: Может есть событие конца отрисовки у LoadingObjectManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Цель - поймать событие, когда меняются объекты в области видимости.

Ловите [`add`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.ObjectCollection-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-add) и [`remove`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.ObjectCollection-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-remove) на `lom.objects.events`. Или [`add`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.OverlayCollection-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-add) и [`remove`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.OverlayCollection-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-remove) на `lom.objects.overlays.events` если хотите поймать момент когда добавляются новые оверлеи.

Оверлей - это отображение гео-объекта, что-то типа View из MVC. OM/LOM/ROM не создают Model и Controller ([`GeoObject`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/)), а только View. `overlaychange` стреляет когда у гео-объекта в OM/LOM/ROM'е меняется опция `overlay` в `options`. Опции объектам в OM/LOM/ROM можно менять через [`om.objects.setObjectOptions`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.ObjectCollection-docpage/#method_detail__setObjectOptions).

> мне нужно посчитать кол-во меток на карте В МОМЕНТ когда эта область видимости меняется

События "все объекты для области видимости загружены" сейчас нет. Если у вас выключена (это дефолт) опция [`splitRequests`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/LoadingObjectManager-docpage/#LoadingObjectManager__param-options.splitRequests), то `add`'ы прилетят вам одной пачкой.

Comment: > События "все объекты для области видимости загружены" сейчас нет. Если у вас выключена (это дефолт) опция splitRequests, то add'ы прилетят вам одной пачкой. - пачкой это значит массовом в аргумент к коллбеку 'add' или по одному в 'add' но 'add'- ов много?